# SQL Server 2012: How to compare query performance if elapsed time changes with each execution?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

This might be a very newbie question, but I'm trying to compare the performance of two queries to illustrate the possible improvement using indexed views. 
Surprisingly, the 'Elapsed time' for the same query varies greatly in consecutive executions from ~160ms to ~80ms, even though I use DROPCLEANBUFFERS and FREEPROCACHE before each query.

Considering that I cannot make the databases larger, how should I compare the queries in this case where the elapsed times are varying so much? Should I not consider the Elapsed time parameter in this case?

Here are the query details and the changing statistics parameters:

Query 1:

```
    SELECT 
     [Manufacturer]
  ,Sum([QAV])/Count(distinct[date]) as AvgQAV
  ,Sum([BackOrders$])/Count(distinct[date])as AvgBackorder$
  ,DATEPART(year,[Date])as Year
    ,DATEPART(month,[Date])as Month
    ,DATEPART(DAY,[DATE]) AS Day
  ,[fixSBU]
  ,[DC Name]
    FROM [dbo].[Copy_IOPSArchivedBackorders1]
  Where
  [Date]>= CONVERT(DATETIME,FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT,DATEADD(dd,-      (DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,DATEADD(MONTH, -12, getDate())))-1), DATEADD(MONTH, -12, getDate())))))  
  AND [Date]<= CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, GETDATE()-1))) 
  Group By
     [Manufacturer]      
     ,DATEPART(year,[Date])
    ,DATEPART(month,[Date])
    ,DATEPART(DAY,[DATE])
  ,[fixSBU]
  ,[DC Name]
  Order By
     DATEPART(year,[Date])
    ,DATEPART(month,[Date])
    ,DATEPART(DAY,[DATE])
```

**Performance: Query1**

Logical reads - 403
Physical reads - 0
read-ahead reads - 56
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 16ms

**Execution - 1**
elapsed time = 150 ms
**Execution - 2**
elapsed time = 83 ms

Query 2:

```
    SELECT [Manufacturer]
    , SumQAV/NumRows AS AvgQAV
    , [SumBackorder$]/NumRows AS AvgBackorders
    , [Year]
    , [Month]
    , [Day]
    , [fixSBU]
    , [DC Name]
    FROM [dbo].[VwCopyIOPSArchivedBackorders1] WITH (NOEXPAND)
    WHERE CAST(CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT('0' + CAST([Month] AS   VARCHAR(2)), 2) + RIGHT('0' + CAST([Day] AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS DATETIME) 
 BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT,DATEADD(dd,-     (DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,DATEADD(MONTH, -12, getDate())))-1), DATEADD(MONTH, -12,  getDate()))))) AND
 CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, GETDATE()-1)))
    Order By
     [Year],[Month],[Day]
```

**Performance: Query 2**

Logical reads - 6
Physical reads - 1
read-ahead reads - 4
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0ms

**Execution - 1**
elapsed time = 167 ms
**Execution - 2**
elapsed time = 70 ms

Comment: Can you put the database in single-user mode while you test, to rule out other activity on the server?

Comment: @Tab - I switched to single user mode through database properties but I'm unable to execute the queries now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with performance checking for anything, don't just run it once.  Run it many many times (thousands) and average the result.  Running once just tells you that one particular execution performed better / worse than one other particular execution.

You can get variance from a lot of things, such as table locks, processor being busy, disk being busy, Windows "helpfully" updating something in the background, etc.  What you want to find is the average case. A way to say that in most circumstances it runs in X ms.  Compare that to your proposed solution that typically runs in Y ms and you can then determine which one is better.  Doing just one execution each just means that you could be comparing a spectacular execution of one with a horrible execution of another.  That will never tell you anything meaningful, other than your test is flawed.

Short answer: run them both a lot and get a good average execution time.

Comment: So, do you recommend manual averaging or are there any procedures for that ? Also, some people also say that Elapsed time depends on a lot of factors and doesn't really matter that much. In that case, do you think the focus should only be on CPU time and logical reads ?

Comment: What I would to is write a quick console app/script that starts a timer, makes the query 10000 times in a loop then stops the timer once the loop finishes.  Print out the total time and the number of executions (and the average, since that is simple math at that point).  Do the same for your second query.  Then you can see the data and tweak and rerun if you come up with something better.

Comment: As far as elapsed time goes, assuming you are using this in a website / other program, it is what you care about.  You want your data back fast.  If you find that getting it back over the network with query A is comparable to query B, then you learn that maybe the optimization isn't worth it.  Maybe you need to look at a better network connection / hardware.  Maybe you need a beefier DB server.  Sure you can test just the CPU time and get a good idea of which query is better, but that may be a small drop in the bucket of what is really causing your problem.

Comment: Great answer! Cleared all of my doubts. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

To see a lot of statistics turn on client statistics (In SSMS Click on Query and select Include Client Statistics). Every time you run tsql statistics will be saved up the last 10 runs. You will see a new tab next to messages with a lot of useful information.

To really see what is going on with your query you will have to learn how to read an Planned and Actual Execution plan, and how to use a wonderful tool called Profiler and finally Extended Events. To get a great, thorough, intro to query plans I would suggest reading SQL Server Execution Plans by Grant Fritchey

**http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/books/65831/**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would you say the Total Execution time that comes in the Client statistics is a wholesome performance measure that is independent of other processes taking place in the server ?

Comment: Absolutely not. SQL Server is a multi-user/multi-tasking product and it also does task in the background. A consistent number is something you may see from running a   set statistics io on  - then you will see (if no one is messing with underlying tables - consistent results.

Comment: Then, while comparing queries, do you think logical reads, physical reads,etc are a more reliable measure than elapsed time or total execution time ?

Comment: For sure - long execution time is like a person with a fever. It indicates something else is wrong and needs to be fixed. If you feel like it please mark answers as correct if you feel you have been helped.